# Excel: Listing Numbers In Between 2 Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I was wondering if anyone knew of a formula to list all the numbers between 2 values, so for example if cell F2 had 12 in it and G2 had 17 in it I'd like a formula that would show 13,14,15,16  In cell H2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with an Excel worksheet function. You will need VBA for that. It can be done with a user-defined function (UDF).

The following code needs to be stored in a code Module. You need to right-click the sheet tab, select View Code. This will open the Visual Basic Editor. Click Insert > Module and then paste the following code:

```
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Integer, MyLast As Integer)
Dim foo As String
Dim i As Long
foo = MyFirst + 1
For i = MyFirst + 2 To MyLast - 1
    foo = foo & "," & i
Next i
InBetween = foo
End Function
```

Now you can use a formula like `=InBetween(F2,G2)` to produce the result you describe.

You need to save the file as a macro-enabled workbook with the XLSM extension. See screenshot for code and user defined function in action.

[image]

Comment: Just judging from your code, without actually testing it. If `MyFirst = 10` and `MyLast = 11`, then doesn't it output `11` ? - I think you should add an `If myFirst >= MyLast-1 Then InBetween = "" ...`

Answer (score 1):

Just because @teylyn said it couldn't be done with a formula - here is a formula based solution:

First you need to create the full list of numbers that you are likely to need as a string, this could be in another cell or my preference would be to create a named range.

So create a new named range called rng and in the Refers to text box add the following formula:

```
=",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,"
```

For this solution to work you have to know the full range upfront, also note the leading and trailing comma.

Then enter the following formula into cell H2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(rng,FIND(","&G2&",",rng)+LEN(G2)),LEFT(rng,FIND(","&F2&",",rng) ),"")
```

To same the tedium of creating the number range string I used the following Powershell code to create and copy it to the clipboard:

```
1..20 -join ',' | % {"=`",$($_),`""} | clip.exe
```

Just change the 20 in the above code for whatever range you require.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 it is very easy to do with the CONCAT-function, e.g. between 10 and 20:

```
=CONCAT(ROW(10:20)&",")
```

Sadly, Office 2016 and onwards do not have this function.