# Excel: How to list the numbers of a sequence of intervals?

Tags: excel, vba, range, sequence, intervals

> I was looking for a way to do what the title says and just found the
>   follow thread:
>   [Excel: Listing Numbers In Between 2 Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337844/excel-listing-numbers-in-between-2-numbers)
>
> But my case is a little different:  there is a cell where will be
>   typed some integer numbers separated by commas and/or hyphens, making
>   multiple intervals (pretty much like that 'page range' field found in
>   many print dialog boxes).
>
> For example: 1-3,9-11,17,19,21-22,25
>
> And I need the result to be returned in another cell but with each
>   number separated on lines, like below:
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 9
>
> 10
>
> 11
>
> 17
>
> 19
>
> 21
>
> 22
>
> 25
>
> I can do this using excel native functions, but for only one interval
>   (e.g.: 1-9).  For anything more than that the formula doesn't work.
>
> Is there a way to accomplish all of this in VBA?
>
> Could some one please point me a direction?
>
> Any help is much appreciated.
>
> Regards

**[Update]**

I have using the code for some weeks, but just realized I need to avoid zeros, repeated numbers and also numbers in descending order.

e.g.

**0**,1,3-**10,8**,12,14,**16,16**,22,**27,24**-30,36,**42,39**

Thus, I need that a #VALUE! error message be returned if the typed numbers were not in ascending order or if zero or repeated numbers were found.

I have working on the code and already solved the aforementioned problems for only the typed intervals (x-y), 
but I can't figure out a solution for the discrete numbers delimited by commas.

Any help is much appreciated.

The code so far:

```
Function RANGEX(strInput As String) As String
Dim intCurrent  As Integer
Dim outputArray() As Variant
Dim intCount As Integer

intCount = 1

For Each i In Split(strInput, ",")
    ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To intCount)

    If InStr(i, "-") > 0 Then
        If CInt(Split(i, "-")(0)) > 0 And CInt(Split(i, "-")(0)) < CInt(Split(i, "-")(1)) Then
            For x = CInt(Split(i, "-")(0)) To CInt(Split(i, "-")(1))
                intCurrent = x
                ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To intCount)
                outputArray(intCount) = intCurrent
                intCount = intCount + 1
            Next x
        Else
            RANGEX = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End If
    Else
        ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To intCount)
        intCurrent = CInt(i)
        outputArray(intCount) = intCurrent
        intCount = intCount + 1
    End If

Next i

RANGEX = Join(outputArray, ",")

End Function
```

Comment: Hey, it sounds like you're pitching a whole coding exercise rather than a specific problem: can you give some examples of what you've tried in VBA?

Comment: @neophlegm Hi Sorry

Comment: Hi @neophlegm. I'm sorry. I think I could not explain my problem in a way anyone could understand it. Anyways, I was trying to make a record file where other users could demand some alterations to some documents (already numbered). Thus, if someone wants to make the same alterations to several documents, the cell with that interval would work together with an engine I made using excel's native functions. And the only missing thing is a VBA function able to do what the title says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, it's possible.

Below an example of working code. Ideally, you would abstract some of the repetitive parts out (resizing the output array and adding the next element), but since your question wasn't about anything specific, here is something that 'just' works - to point you in the right direction. Put what you provided into cell A1 and the required output will be written to cell B1:

```
Sub Testing()
Dim strInput As String
Dim strOutput As String
Dim intCurrent  As Integer
Dim outputArray() As Variant
Dim intCount As Integer

intCount = 1

strInput = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
For Each i In Split(strInput, ",")
    ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To intCount)
    If InStr(i, "-") > 0 Then
        For x = CInt(Split(i, "-")(0)) To CInt(Split(i, "-")(1))
            intCurrent = x
            ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To intCount)
            outputArray(intCount) = intCurrent
            intCount = intCount + 1
        Next x
    Else
        ReDim Preserve outputArray(1 To intCount)
        intCurrent = CInt(i)
        outputArray(intCount) = intCurrent
        intCount = intCount + 1
    End If
Next i
strOutput = Join(outputArray, vbCrLf)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = strOutput
End Sub
```

On top of this, certain assumptions are made about the input (separator is ',').

Of course you can convert this to a function in order to be able to use it as a formula directly in Excel.

Comment: Hey @pwwolff. Thank you very much for putting me in the right direction! 
I converted it to a function, but the result is not separating the numbers in lines anymore. Could you help me? I will answer my question posting the new code.

Comment: Hey @pwwolff. You nailed it! 'Wrap Text' is the answer! Again, thank you!

Comment: @PeterWhite great - could you accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Hey. May I ask your help for the last time? Just edited my question.