# I'm using an "InBetween" UDF in Excel VBA and it works for 43 rows, then stops working

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Using this [VBA User Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337844/excel-listing-numbers-in-between-2-numbers) that yields a list of numbers that are in between a given set of parameter numbers. It works until the parameter numbers are greater than 29,999 in row 43. 
This is the UDF Code:

```
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Integer, MyLast As Integer)
Dim foo As String
Dim i As Long
foo = MyFirst + 1
For i = MyFirst + 2 To MyLast - 1
    foo = foo & "," & i
Next i
InBetween = foo
End Function
```

And I use the created =InBetween formula to return all numbers in between the parameter numbers. I'm also using a concatenate function to include the parameter numbers in the list. All of Column A and B are formatted the same.

[image]

Comment: Integer data type can only hold up to 32767. Change your MyFirst/MyLast to Long

Comment: Also, there is no advantage to using `Integer` in place of `Long` - Excel allocates all the memory for a `Long`, but prevents half of it from being used if you declare it as an `Integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no purpose in using a `Integer` variable. They easily overflow since they can't hold that large numbers. Instead use `Long` data type.

On top of that, you might want to look into rewriting your `Function` as per:

```
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Long, MyLast As Long) As String
    InBetween = Join(Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(Row(" & MyFirst & ":" & MyLast & "))"), ",")
End Function
```

That would up to `1048576` (In Excel 2019 at least)